# Losing state value after function is finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spfx

I'm new to react concept, I don't understand why I lose the value of the state after the `.then()`
I lose the `ISPList` state value but I did set state :(
appreciate any help.

```
export default class Cartable extends 
React.Component<IMainCartableProps, ICartableState> {
constructor(props: IMainCartableProps, state: ICartableState) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      status: "Ready",
      ISiteCollections: [],
      ISPLists:[],
      ISPTaskItems:[],
    }
   }


  public _getListOfLists(context: WebPartContext): Promise<ISPLists[]> {
    
    this.state.ISiteCollections.map(async (siteCollection:any)=>{
      
      let url = siteCollection.SPSiteUrl + `/forms/_api/web/lists? 
    $filter=Hidden eq false and BaseTemplate eq 107`;
      //console.log(url)
       let config: SPHttpClientConfiguration = new 
  SPHttpClientConfiguration({
        defaultODataVersion: ODataVersion.v3})
        
         new Promise<ISPLists[]>( async (resolve, reject)=>{
          this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(url, config, { headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;charset=utf-8" }})
            .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
              //console.log(response.status)
              if(response.status==200){
                response.json().then((results: any) => {
                  //let resultsList = results.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows;
                  console.log(results)
                  results.value.map((result:any)=>{
                    TaskLists.push({
                      title: result.Title,
                      Id:result.Id
                    })
                    
                  })
        
                  //console.log(TaskLists.length)
                  //this.setState({ ISPLists:TaskLists })
                  //console.log(this.state.ISPLists.length)
                  //resolve(TaskLists);
                  this.setState({ISPLists:TaskLists})
                  
                    //this.setState({ ISPLists:TaskLists})
                    //console.log(this.state.ISPLists[1].title)
                    //this._getTaskItems()
                })

                
              }
             // return response.json();
             console.log(TaskLists.length)
            })
   
          })
          
    })
    console.log(TaskLists.length)
    console.log("Hereeeee")
    this.state.ISPLists.map(SPList=>{
      console.log(SPList.title)
    })
    
    
    return 
   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with this code.

1. You are using a map method,  returning nothing, and adding async operations
2. `this.setState` replaces the existing state, it doesn't merge your new state with the existing state

Solution:

1. If you just need to loop through `ISiteCollections` and send API requests
   , then just simply use `forEach` or `for` loop to loop through the array
2. To merge your new state with the existing state, use the es6 spread operator.`this.setState({ispLists:[...this.state.ispLists , ...TaskLists ]})`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about your problem as Im not working with react for long time but as for debugging this:
1: Make a console.log for the ISPLists just after setState to make sure that the value has been set correctly.
2: Make sure you are looping through it after setState (as I didnt found any async/await in your code).

For cleaner way: make a separate function for setState ISPList value in order to have more flexibility on it and debugging easier. This really could help to debug it.